# MAMP Pro does not log PHP errors

Tags: mamp

I have been struggling with MAMP pro for past few months. Tried contacting Appsolute (#24294) but got no help. Somehow Mamp Pro has stopped recording all PHP errors.

My configuration: http://prntscr.com/itmqm5

PHP conf files from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf
php.ini file :https://ufile.io/edacj
PHP 7.2.1 ini : https://ufile.io/8bl8q

Comment: Why downvote ? I have read all the rules and terms , please specify a reason for downvoting !

Comment: Since someone marked this topic as -1,I am left with no choice but to create a new question to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found that my MAMP installation was hacked. I had to clean up everything and re-install MAMP pro to fix this.