# Wordpress Admin PHP Errors Not Showing up in Host Error Log (MAMP Installation)

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, php-ini, wordpress-admin

I have a weird situation where Wordpress PHP some errors are not showing up neither in my MAMP error logs, nor in my per-host error log.

When I `tail -f /Application/MAMP/logs/*error*` the MAMP error logs I see:

```
[Wed Apr 18 00:18:23 2018] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.4.45.fcgi"
```

Nothing when I `tail -f <local-site-host-path>/*error*` I see no updates whatsoever, even tho I have added a `php.ini` and `.user.ini` (just in case) to log errors, have `chmod 777` all error_log files, and have this in both .ini files:

```
log_errors = On
error_reporting = 8589934592
error_log = /<local-site-host-path>/error_log
display_errors = 1
```

**NOTES**:

- if I intentionally make a PHP code typo, I see the errors in the MAMP logs but not in the host logs.
- MAMP installed on a Macbook,
- Running a few Wordpress sites (latest 4.9.5) with all plug-ins up to date) (error is not showing up for all of them).
- The actual 500 server error is happening ƒor /wp-admin/* ONLY for a site  (wp 4.9.5) and partially for another site (wp 4.9.5);  Yet a third site's /wp-admin/*   (wp 4.9.2) works just fine (!?!?!?)

Or am I being hacked (as Ripul Kumar points out here, but with no further information on what symptoms were present that showed him he was hacked: [MAMP Pro doest no log PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377940/mamp-pro-doest-no-log-php-errors)) =>  I ACTUALLY REINSTALLED MAMP + MAMP Pro to see if that made any difference. NO, it didn't.  EXACT SAME result.

THANK YOU

Comment: OK, there is an update.  I was able to get over the mysterious road-block, but trying to disable Wordpress plugins until it worked.  So there was an offending plugin that was somehow preventing errors from getting logged in the `error_log`.  I would still like to know what in the world that condition prevents error loggin.  Anyone?